# Skyscanner API and website data discrepancy

Tags: skyscanner

The Skyscanner API gives different results than Skyscanner website.

For the flight from any airport in Warsaw to any airport in Wrocław, if I use the API the cheapest option is 303.99 zł.

[image]

[image]

This flight is operated by LOT (LO). Other available flights are operated either by LOT (LO) or by Lufthansa (LH).

On the other hand, if I make the same query using Skyscanner website, the cheapest flight costs 42 zł and is operated by Ryanair (FR).

[image]

link: https://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights/wars/wro/161111/161112/airfares-from-warsaw-to-wroclaw-in-november-2016.html?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=1&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=home#results

However, if I uncheck Ryanair at the left hand side panel, I receive very similar results to those from the API.

[image]

Link: https://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights/wars/wro/161111/161112/airfares-from-warsaw-to-wroclaw-in-november-2016.html?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=1&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=home#results

What is more, if I enter the API test as an unlogged user, I can again retrieve the Ryanair flight. The test is available at: http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/FlightsLivePricingQuickStart

Images:

[image]
[image]

Can you reproduce this behavior? Is there something I am doing wrong about the API? How can I retrieve Ryanair’s prices programmatically?

Comment: Make sure country, currency and locale are exactly the same for API calls and the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong, I've the same problem. In fact, I've taken the example apiKey from the test site and copied it to my code (for testing), and it shows Ryanair flights. But not with my apiKey. It appears that they are deliberately excluding Ryanair from the regular api results. I've contacted Skyscanner for Business support weeks ago, and haven't received a reply.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, I only intermittently see Ryanair results...

Comment: Skyscanner for Business support are telling me that Ryanair results shouldn't be expected in the API, that doesn't explain why I have seen them in the past though..